# Regex find first 2 characters of every word in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

In Vim, how do you find the first 2 characters of every word in a file and replace it.

I'm actually looking to use matchadd for a plugin, but I'm struggling with vim's particular regex.

I have tried:

```
\w\{2}
```

But this gets the next set of 2 characters.

I have also tried:

```
\w\{2}\{-}
```

But this doesn't work as it's a syntax error.

I really want a non greedy regex on any 2 characters per word.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out all I really needed was:

```
\<\w\{2}
```

Thanks Birei for the hints (upvoted).  Note, for this to work properly, I did not need the "\>" etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try with word-boundaries. In [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) are `\<` for the beginning of word and `\>` for the end. I use very-magic option (`\v`) so I don't need to escape them:

```
:s/\v<\w{2}(\w*)>/\1/g
```

Comment: This was VERY helpful, but I get Pattern not found.

Comment: In `vim` if you apply a substitution command to a line without a match, it throws a **Pattern not found** error. You have to ensure before it that it will match with the `global` command. Look at its help page: `help global`